# What is best normalizing data before or after building cubes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

First I'm still learning; so is it better to normalize data before building cubes or after? or cubes require demoralize tables?

This question is regarding MS SQL Server.

Comment: these two articles might help clear your doubts [Data Normalization](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-database-normalization-in-sql-server/) and [Building Cubes in SQL](https://www.sqlshack.com/build-cube-scratch-using-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas/)

Comment: Cubes are usually built from data warehouse, which has highly denormalized data. Data warehouse loads data from various data sources, including highly normalized relational tables